# VBA Excel Converter with Transposing

Tags: excel, vba

Using an export file from an application, I must convert a macro-enabled workbook into a non macro-enabled one for import into a new application using a Macro. With this document, there exists parent and child requirements. In order for the new application to accept these, there must not be duplicate columns. I've handled the task of converting the file, but am having trouble with transposing data properly.

Here is a table to better visualize the data I have been given.

Parent | Child

| Trace ID | Name | Trace ID | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 2 | Cell 3 | Cell 4 |
|  |  | Cell 7 | Cell 8 |
|  |  | Cell 11 | Cell 12 |
|  |  | Cell 15 | Cell 16 |
| Cell 17 | Cell 18 | Cell 19 | Cell 20 |

I'm relatively new to VBA in Excel. I have a prompt asking the user to choose a macro-enabled file. In order to mitigate user error, a filter has been created and multiselect has been disabled. The current workbook is then copied and pasted to the new. We then have the range of the parent and child for transposing. A IF ELSE loop is created to check the
cell in a row. If IsEmpty = True, then it will paste the transposed values to the row and move on to the next until all has been transposed. I'm wondering if a DO WHILE would have been better for this?

```
Dim fd As Office.FileDialog

Dim nextEmptyCell As Range

Set fld = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim MyFileName As String
Dim Current As Workbook
Dim Temp As Workbook

Set myCFile = fld.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\c66188\Documents\EICAS_Macro\myFile.xlsx", True)
'Choose file prompt (filtered to Macro-Enabled Excel)
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With fd

    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsm", 1
    .Title = "Choose an Macro-Enabled Excel file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False

    'initialFileName is placeholder
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"

    If .Show = True Then
        strFile = .SelectedItems(1)

    End If

End With

'Taking a copy of the active workbook and pasting to the new
Set Current = ActiveWorkbook
'Taking the active sheet of the active workbook and copying contents
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy
'Setting Temp with copied values(pasting)
Set Temp = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With Temp.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

'Range to select
'Columns("P:AC").Copy
'Transposing them to next empty row
'Range("A:O").Copy

'This part is working as intended (shows that cell is empty)
Set nextEmptyCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)

If IsEmpty(nextEmptyCell) Then
MsgBox "Empty cell found. Populating..."
'.Paste
Else
MsgBox "Data found. Moving to next cell."

End If


'Dim change to become compatible with .xls files
MyFileName = Current.Path & "\" & Left(Current.Name, Len(Current.Name) - 5) & ".xlsx"

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Temp.Close SaveChanges:=True

'Window to notify conversion is complete

MsgBox "Data has been transfered. Ready for import."

End Sub
```

Comment: If the presented sample data is located in a workbook that will be opened, what does the result look like and will it be located in the workbook containing this code? Also, explain what the .xlsx file is all about. Is its creation really necessary? BTW, the trailing question mark in the filter will ensure no file is shown. Get rid of it.